# updating record: how to check if a new file has been uploaded PHP

Tags: php, post, sql-update, crud

I am learning PHP, so forgive me if my question is somewhat silly.

I have created a form to update records in my db, which includes changing your name, age and image. When I update a record without changing the image it deletes the image (base64 string) from the updated row.

How can I check if an image has been changed or not, and if not: keep the present one unchanged or put into other words, not update that specific field. here is my php script for the update:

```
if( !is_null( $db ) && array_key_exists( 'edit_person', $_POST ) ):
  $pn = filter_var( trim( $_POST['name'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
  $n = filter_var( trim($_POST['age'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
  // check if another image has been uploaded
  $img = filter_var( trim($_POST['img'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
  // if not: don't update img
  $id = filter_var( trim ( $_POST['id'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
  update_person( $db, $id, $img, $n, $pn ); 
 endif;
```

the update_person function:

```
   function update_person( &$db, $id, $img, $age, $name ){ 
   if( is_null( $db ) ) return '';
   $sql = "
    UPDATE
      xxx
    SET
      xxx.name = :name,
      xxx.age = :age,
      xxx.img = :img
    WHERE
      xxx.id = :id
    ";
  $vraag = $db->prepare( $sql );
  $vraag->bindValue( ':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $vraag->bindValue( ':age', $age, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $vraag->bindValue( ':img', $img, PDO::PARAM_STR ); 
  $vraag->bindValue( ':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
  $vraag->execute();
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I think you can store the md5 value of image and use md5 value to vaildate the image has been change or not.

Comment: Is it an image the user can upload, or are there only predefined images you can choose from?

Comment: Any file they wish encoded as base64 string

Comment: What happens if the user empties his username or age field? You have to build in some logic while creating your query, skipping the columns you don't want to change  because the $_POST value is empty.

Comment: Thank you michel. Is there an example of how this works? In other words where can I read up on conditional querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. If the **$img** variable is not set, do not update the **image column** in table

```
if( !is_null( $db ) && array_key_exists( 'edit_person', $_POST ) ):
  $pn = filter_var( trim( $_POST['name'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
  $n = filter_var( trim($_POST['age'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
  // check if another image has been uploaded
  $img = filter_var( trim($_POST['img'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
  // if not: don't update img      
  $id = filter_var( trim ( $_POST['id'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

  if(!empty($img) && $img != '') :
    update_person( $db, $id, $n, $pn ); 
  else:
    update_person( $db, $id, $img, $n, $pn ); 
  endif;
endif;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this helps thank you. I should do this in the function update_person right? else I get a missing arguments error. I will update the post with the function included.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you. Yes,  you need to put if condition in function update_person